# Dealing with differentiating looks in multiple browers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am building my first complicated website. Everything I code looks good in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but I always have trouble with my CSS in Internet Explorer. I know Internet Explorer is known for this, but I am getting very disgruntled and I want to give up. Should I not worry about Internet Explorer for the moment, and just make a separate stylesheet later? What is the best practice?

Comment: Conditional callouts to specific stylesheets.

Comment: Here is a starting point http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/

Comment: @Scott - "Conditional comments" not 'callouts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to support as many browsers as possible, it will be a time saver if you can do this with only 1 stylesheet. Most times if a site is broken in ie ( except for ie6 ) it's going to minor things, but if it drastically different then I would look at your overall css and html. Chrome and Firefox are forgiving and are much easier to develop for, but they also help you out.

I never do special stylesheets for site unless it's ie6 and even now I no longer support ie6, depending on your clients needs you should be able to forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should continue with the website and when you are finished look at IE with a separate stylesheet. Doing all at once takes longer time, at the beginning doing one at a time is the best practice in my opinion.